# How to prove a map $f:R \rightarrow C(X, R)$, defined as $f(t) = v_t$, is an embedding, where $X$ is a tychonoff space and $R$, a real line.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I want to know a compatible criterion to prove that the map $f:R \rightarrow C(X, R)$ as $f(t) = v_t$, $v_t$ being a constant map, $t \in R$, is an embedding.

Comment: $v_t$ is the constant map with value $t$, I suppose?

Comment: Yes it is a constant map, i forgot to mention it earlier.

Comment: What is the topology on $C(X,\Bbb R)$? pointwise, compact-open?

Comment: Lets suppose the topology is Uniform topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the uniform topology (as suggested in the comments):

If $B_t(r)$ is an open ball of radius $t>0$ around $r\in \Bbb R$, then $f[B_t(r)] \cap f[\Bbb R] = \mathbf{B}(v_r, t) \cap f[\Bbb R]$, where $\mathbf{B}(f, t) = \{g \in C(X,\Bbb R): \forall x \in X: |f(x)-g(x)| < t\}$ is a basic uniform-open set in  $C(X,\Bbb R)$. This shows $f$ is open as map from $\Bbb R$ onto $f[\Bbb R]$.

It's also clear that if $r_n \to r$ in $\Bbb R$, then $f(r_n) \to f(r)$ in the uniform (or also pointwise or compact-open) topology on $C(X,\Bbb R)$ showing continuity of $f$ as well. As $f$ is clearly 1-1, $f$ is an embedding.

Comment: I was facing problem in proving it an open map, now it is very clear. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, i have a bit doubt about the same function while replacing the real line $R$ with any metric space $Y$. How to prove the same for metric space $Y$.

Comment: @MirAaliya I think the same argument works for any metric space. You’re not using anything specific to the reals.